# Update panel not working in Safari browser

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, browser-compatibility, updatepanel

I have a visual web part in which one button and a label inside an update panel. When I run the web part in IE and Firefox it works fine but it does not work in Safari.

My declarative part is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlFirst" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" OnClick="btnClick_Click" Text="Click Here" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My code is:

```
int count = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]);
    CallJavascript();
}

private void CallJavascript()
{
    string script = @"Sys.Browser.WebKit = {}; //Safari 3 is considered WebKit"+
                    @"if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf( 'WebKit/' ) > -1 )"+
                     @"{ Sys.Browser.agent = Sys.Browser.WebKit; Sys.Browser.version = parseFloat( navigator.userAgent.match(/WebKit\/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/)[1]);"+
                      @"Sys.Browser.name = 'WebKit';}";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,GetType(),"Script",script,true);
}

protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMsg.Text = "Refresh Value:" + count;
    ViewState["count"] = ++count;
}
```

I searched over internet for the issue and found [this](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/10/Gotcha-WebKit-%28Safari-3-and-Google-Chrome%29-Bug-with-ASPNET-AJAX.aspx) link to troubleshoot the problem. That's why I included CallJavascript() method. But it's not working in my case. 
I debugged the program and found that the when I click from Safari the button_click does not fire. The control just goes away from page load.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.

I am testing one thing that might do the trick: Make all your update panels on `updatemode=conditional`.

This is not working so i will try the second solution in Ali SharePoint answer: [UpdatePanel in sharepoint not working in Safari browser](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77748/updatepanel-in-sharepoint-not-working-in-safari-browser)