# UpdatePanel is not working in SAFARI Brower for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: error

I am using UpdatePanel in my SharePoint application. But UpdatePanel is not working. I have tried below solution.Sometime its working and sometime not.

[UpdatePanel in sharepoint not working in Safari browser](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77748/updatepanel-in-sharepoint-not-working-in-safari-browser)

Am not able resolve this issue. Please help me to resolve

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in OnInIt event of web part,

```
if (Page.Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("SAFARI"))
{
   ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
   if (sm != null)
   {
      sm.EnablePartialRendering = false;
   }
}
```

Build and deploy.

It fixes your issue :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to add some more point. I am using application pages in that i have used Updatepanel. And Script manager is referred in the custom master page.I am not using web part.? Can you give some brief information?

Comment: I have tried this by overriding the application page init method its working fine. But, Cant we able to trigger EnablePartialRendering for safari?